# Modeling a sequential Random Vector as a Random Processes

Tags: random-variables, gaussian

I'm studying random vectors. For a problem that I'm studying, I have a random vector that has a sequential nature. I know that modeling random variables as sequential processes is considered in the literature as random processes which is similar to modeling random vectors. However, I need to model my random vector sequentially. Is there a way to use random vectors in random processes?

Comment: A stochastic process can take values in any measurable space. A sequence of random vectors can simply be seen as a $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued stochastic process.

Comment: More simply, a random vector $(X_1, ..., X_n)$ is a collection of $n$ different random variables.  Similarly, a random sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a collection of a countably infinite number of random variables.